# Multiple digit HTML accesskey?

Tags: html

This site uses multiple digit accesskeys:

http://indian.embassy.uk.com/

eg:

```
<a title="Indian Embassy in UK" href="index.php" class="l1" accesskey="201">Home</a>
```

I assume that this is an error and not some clever use of unicode, etc?

Comment: Looks like an error to me... I'd never heard of `accesskey` before, but after some testing I couldn't get any multiple-character-things to work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the website in question no longer has the tag mentioned in the question.